# Creating an html list from a multidimenional array - creating group headings

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I am using a json api to bring data in a wordpress function, this is for a sports related website and the purpose of this particular call is to create a list of fixtures for the current competition. I need the data to be grouped by match date with the most recent date first, My first step has been to create a new array that groups the data by matchdate as a $key

```
<?php
$matchLists = json_decode(json_encode($fixture_data), True);

$newlist = array();
foreach ($matchLists as $key => $matchitem) {
    if (array_key_exists('matchDate', $matchitem)) {
        $newlist[$matchitem['matchDate']][$key] = ($matchitem);
    }
}
?>
```

This returns a new array grouped as I expected - but the problem I am having is how to then use the `matchDate` converted to datetime to act as the heading for each fixture grouping as now each item in the `$newlist` contains a `matchDate`. an example of the `$newlist` 
[in attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdbVO.png)

My first thought was to create a variable the used the 'match date' labels of the newly created arrays but when I tried this It said the label did not exist.
I then thought to try using [] to go down levels of the array and again this did not return the desired results
Can anybody help?

Comment: can you post what you've tried?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I figured out how to get the headings using key and value:  foreach($newlist as $key => $value)
         {
          $fixtureDate = date('D j M Y ga', strtotime($key));

          d($key);
          
          $return .= '<li><h4>' . $fixtureDate . '</h4></li><li><ul>'; but from here I am having issues displaying the data from array underneath these headers. I have also tried to create tables but most of my cells come back as "array"